Trying to avoid Timeouts testing my odoo app with Playwright
I'm having some troubles while testing my odoo app with playright.
I often find playwright clicking too fast for elements to be activated already, or to modify a field, then try to do something else immediatly, only to see that something be canceled by an "actualisation" of the page, caused by the previous field modification.
Image here
For an exemple of the first case, i choose the value "Assurance axa" in the dropdown, and i must then empty the field, but if i do it like this :

await odoo.try_to_select_x2m("Assurance axa", "source_service_line_id")
await odoo.empty_field("source_service_line_id")

It chooses the value, then empty the field immediately, but then the field gets 'actualized', and the field retakes the value  "Assurance axa".
So far i make the test pass like this
await odoo.try_to_select_x2m("Assurance axa", "source_service_line_id")
await odoo.wait_for_http_response_with_url_substring("lease4.amendment.service_line")       // Need to be addressed differently
await odoo.empty_field("source_service_line_id")

async wait_for_http_response_with_url_substring(url_substring) {
    await this.page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes(url_substring));
    await this.page.waitForTimeout(500)    // To let the page update after receiving its response.
}

but as you can see, it is not even enough to wait for the associated http response, i have to add a timeout, and this is not viable long-term.
For my second exemple, first i have my login function
async login(username: string) {
        let password = await this.get_password_from_vault(username)

        await this.page.goto('**************************');
        await this.page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('web.assets_frontend_lazy.js'))
        await this.page.getByLabel('Your Email').fill(username)
        await this.page.getByLabel('Password').fill(password)
        await this.page.getByRole('button', {name: 'Confirm'}).click()
        await this.page.waitForURL(/active_id=mail\.box_inbox/)
    }

where i have to wait for the page to be hydrated ( i think that it is what the lazy.js http response indicates) before clicking on the 'Confirm' button.
I have been told by a more experienced colleague to avoid waitForResponse as much as possible, and for obvious reasons not to have any waitForTimeout, but i don't see how to handle these situations differently.
For my second problem, i have this code
await odoo.navigate("CRM", "Sales", "My Pipeline")
await odoo.wait_for_http_response_with_url_substring("crm.lead")    
await odoo.click_on_button_by_accessible_name_or_data_name('Create')

that only works thanks to the timeout, if i try to do
await odoo.navigate("CRM", "Sales", "My Pipeline")
await odoo.wait_for_url("model=crm.lead&view_type=kanban")
await odoo.click_on_button_by_accessible_name_or_data_name('Create')

then playwright clicks on the button, but nothing happens, and yet i don't see any javascript in the http requests that could indicates a lazy loading/hydration of the button, but the button works fine if i wait 500 ms.
I'm quite confused about why this button isn't "activated", but i have to wait a bit before being able to use it.
Anyways, i would appreciate any idea on how to handle these situations without using this waitForResponse function.
Thank you for reading all this, have a good day.
Explained in the subject.

Can you share an example page you're automating? It's hard to help otherwise.
